# Problems with template.ParseFiles

Tags: go

I have the following http.Handle function (simplified):

```
func loginHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        cwd, _ := os.Getwd()
        t, err := template.ParseFiles(filepath.Join(cwd, "./views/login.html"))

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "503 - Error")
            fmt.Println(err)
        } else {
            t.Execute(w, nil)
        }

}
```

It works as intended when using `go build main.go`, however - after running `go install`, I get an error that it can't find the file (as it is now compiled to `/bin/<appname>` (where there is no views folder). Apart from adding a views folder to the `/bin` directory or hardcoding the path, how can I get the `template.ParseFiles()` to find the correct path?

Is there some standard method to include 'static' resources to be used for the comiled program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard method to include static resources for a compiled program; however [one](http://12factor.net/config) common convention is to store configuration in environment variables.

For example, when running your app, put the expected environment variable in the environment:

```
$> TEMPLATE_VIEWS=/var/local/app/views myapp
```

And in your code you would find the folder:

```
func loginHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    t, err := template.ParseFiles(filepath.Join(os.Getenv("TEMPLATE_VIEWS"), "login.html"))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "503 - Error")
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        t.Execute(w, nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll mark this as the solution tomorrow if there are no better answers provided (in-case there are any other methods people use).